# Syncing content between stage and prod

Tags: 8, staging

Drupal 8, two versions of a site - dev and production.

How to move changes, especially changes in content from dev to production without destroying DB on production?

I know we have Features for configuration, but what about content?

Ideally, I would like to be able to add nodes, pages and edit existing ones, and then carry changes to the prod site, without destroying changes users created on the dev site - comments, new registrations and such.

What's the solution here? Export content to code?

Can someone give step-by-step on dev cycle?

Answer (score 1):

I think the content synchronization module might be a good bet.

https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync

It has its own documentation page here:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/content-synchronization

There is mention of Drush commands in it.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've discovered this site: http://www.drupaldeploy.org:

> A next generation comprehensive yet easy to use content staging
>   solution built for Drupal developers and end users

There are several modules that work together, the "base" module should be [Deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy):

> The Deploy module is designed to allow users to easily stage and
>   preview content for a Drupal site. Deploy automatically manages
>   dependencies between entities (like node references). It is designed
>   to have a rich API which can be easily extended to be used in a
>   variety of content staging situations.

On drupaldeploy.org you can find related modules.

Answer (score 0):

There are modules that export content to code:
https://www.drupal.org/project/defaultcontent
https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content

You may also be able to get something working using Migrate, which is very powerful in D8.