# How do I migrate from a site using a core version to another one using the same version?

Tags: migrations

I like to change the web-hosting provider. I want to remove un-necassary and useless stuff (e.g. modules, content types that aren't used from the site).

I have no idea how to do this. Is there a module for migrating only stuff which is in use? The migration modules I found only consider migration from previous versions to Drupal 8, not from Drupal 8 to Drupal 8.

Comment: Title reads 'from drupal 8 to drupal 8', but the body reads 'not from Drupal 8 to Drupal 8', these are contradictory. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: It says "The migration modules I found consider only the migration from former versions to Drupal 8, not to Drupal 8 to Drupal 8." In other words, "I didn't find any migration module that would help for my case."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For migration of configuration, use [*Configuration Management*](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/managing-your-sites-configuration) in Drupal 8 core.

For content, you can use the following approaches:

- [Deploy module](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) for content staging
- [Default Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content) (see also [this one](https://www.drupal.org/project/defaultcontent))
- [Drupal 8 migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_drupal_d8) (provides sources for Nodes, Users and Terms including configurable fields)

There are other services which can help you with content staging such as:

- [Drupal Deploy](http://www.drupaldeploy.org/)
- [Entity Pilot](https://entitypilot.com/content/new-beta6-share-and-move-content-between-different-drupal-sites)

Related:

- [How do I export my site structure?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/180260/1908)
- [How do I deploy/manage similar sites from an unique profile, without dumps?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/187297/1908)
- [Synching development and production site versions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/210594/1908)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just uninstall those modules and remove the configuration you no longer need?

Migration is a complicated task that requires a lot of work.

And to switch the webhost, you just need to copy the files and database, no need to mix those two things together. Clean up your site first and then switch the host. Otherwise you'll never be sure if a problem is caused by the host change or changed configuration

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have no experiences with migration. I am a little bit frightend to remove things in drupal.
long time ago I made the experience with an uninstalled module having trouble to reinstall. Maybe this was a bug and is fixed now.